# Java extract text from text file from a certain point on the text

Tags: java, filter, inputstream, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I have created a method with `BufferedReader` that opens a text file created previously by the program and extracts some characters. My problem is that it extracts the whole line and I want to extract only after a specified character, the `:`.

Here is my `try/catch` block:

```
try {
    InputStream ips = new FileInputStream("file.txt"); 
    InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(ips); 
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(ipsr); 

    String ligne;
        while((ligne = br1.readLine()) != null) {
            if(ligne.startsWith("Identifiant: ")) {
                System.out.println(ligne);
                id = ligne;
            }
            if(ligne.startsWith("Pass: ")) {
                System.out.println(ligne);
                pass = ligne;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ligne);
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(pass);
        br1.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Error. "+ex.getMessage());
    }
```

At the moment, I return to my `String` id the entire `ligne`, and same for `pass` – by the way, all the `sysout` are tests and are useless there.

If anybody knows how to send to id the line after the `:`and not the entire line, I probably searched bad, but google wasn't my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's only one : symbol in the string you can go with

```
 id = ligne.substring(ligne.lastIndexOf(':') + 1);
```

Comment: There is indeed only one `:`per line, It works great. Thanks for your answer, I discover the substring method, very powerfull.

Comment: or `id = id.substring(id.indexOf(':') + 1);` if you want to start after first `:` ...

Comment: I just edited my answer, you should substring from ligne not id, sorry.

Comment: No problem for the mistake Stugal, I adapted your answer to my code, like this: `pass = ligne.substring(ligne.lastIndexOf(':')+2);` :)

Answer (score 0):

Use StringUtils

> StringUtils.substringAfter(id ,":"),

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to do a `split()` on `ligne`?

If you use `String[] splittedLigne = ligne.split(":");`, you will have the following in `splittedLigne`:

`splittedLigne[0]` -> What is before the `:`

`splittedLigne[1]` -> What is after the `:`

This will give you what you need for every line. Also, this will work for you if you have more than one `:`.

Comment: split method, thank you for your answer, I'll try it too :) Maybe better if it works for more than une `:`per line.